# Get downloadable product sample link in newsletter SubscriberController Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, product

In my Magento store I have added downloadable products and if user want to download this product user need to subscribe our newsletter. for that I have added newsletter subscriber block in view.phtml file. Code is below.

```
<?php $download = Mage::registry('current_product')->getTypeId();?>
            <?php 
                if($download == 'downloadable')
                { ?>
                
                <div class="pop-upss">
                    <input type="button" onclick="showMrnlePopup();" value="To Download This Product You Need To Subscribe Our Newsletter" name="submit"/>
                </div>
            <?php }     ?>
```

I have set onclick function and when user will click on this button newsletter pop-up will open.

In newsletter PHTML file I get current product's id using below code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pro_id" value="<?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();?>">
```

Now we go to SubscriberController.php file and it's newAction(). I get current product id in newAction() using below code.

```
$product_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('pro_id');
```

Now what I want using this product Id is:

1). I want all data about current product. I got this is using below code:

```
if($product_id) {
    $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product = $obj->load($product_id);
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_product->getData());
    die; 
}
```

2). if this product is downloadable then I want its sample data and its link to download product but I cannot get current product's download link. My code for get download link is below.

```
if($_product->hasSamples()) {
    $_samples = $this->getSamples();
    
    foreach ($_samples as $_sample){
         echo $samplePath = $_sample->getBasePath();
         echo $sampleFile = $_sample->getSampleFile();
    }
} else {
    echo 'not getting anything here...';
}
```

When I run above code it goes into else part and echo 'not getting anything here...'.

Comment: Can you show me the complete `newAction()` method from your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting these links is a bit complicated. I prepared a little snippet how to get the sample files and the normal links.

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('pro_id');

    if($product_id) {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

        if($product->getTypeId() == 'downloadable') {
            /** @var Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Sample_Collection $samples */
            $samples = Mage::getModel('downloadable/sample')->getCollection()->addProductToFilter($product_id);

            if($samples->count() > 0) {
                foreach($samples as $sample) {
                    /** @var Mage_Downloadable_Model_Sample $sample */
                    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'downloadable/files/samples' . $sample->getSampleFile();
                    echo 'Sample URL: ' . $url . "<br>";
                }
            }

            /** @var Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Link_Collection $links */
            $links = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')->getCollection()->addProductToFilter($product);

            if($links->count() > 0) {
                foreach($links as $link) {
                    /** @var Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link $link */
                    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'downloadable/files/links' . $link->getLinkFile();
                    echo 'Link URL: ' . $url;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to load collections of `downloadable/sample` and `downloadable/link` and pass a product model or a product id to it. That's the Magento way ;-)

Comment: @codeedge I used your code and I get download product link in SubscriberController.php but when I click this link it is redirect to home page but when I click on same link that is genetated default for downloadable product on view page it's open PDF file so can you tell me what is the reason for this issue?

Comment: I get downloadable product link in SubscriberController.php 's newaction now if I want it to download automatically when this method is called then what I have to do? do you have any idea?

Comment: @watson Please create a new question for this on StackOverflow, as this has nothing to do with this question  here. Thanks!